# The Principia Mathematica's missing chapters

Tags: mathematics, mathematical-logic

The numbering of the chapters of Bertrand Russell and Alfred Whitehead's Principia Mathematica is the following :

1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 30, etc

overall, there's about 30 chapters missing from this numbering schemes. Is this some kind of numbering where he left gaps intentionally to not have to renumber them later on? (there are technically 10 chapters per sections)

Was that common practice back then?

Comment: Every major Section start with a new "decade". The only strange thing is that Section B starts from *9.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA maybe 6 was printed upside down?

Comment: I think that there is no misterious reason behind: the chapters fit into a numbering schema defined top-down from the start of the three-volumes treatise (whose redaction takes 10 years) in order to avoid that some addition can implies the re-checking of (many many) internal references, as well as to accomodate additions without destroing the parts already ready for printing.